# ffmpeg: Infinite length output when overlaying subtitles onto black image

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to do some analysis of image-based subtitles by outputting them as a sequence of PNGs to a pipe. My command line looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $INPUTFILE -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:s:5]overlay[v]" -shortest -map "[v]" -c:v png -f image2pipe - | pike subspng.pike
```

In theory, `-shortest` should mean that the stream stops at the shortest input, which would be roughly seven minutes of input file. Instead, my script receives an infinite sequence of black frames after the last frame of subtitles, until I send FFMPEG a SIGINT. Placing `-shortest` before `-filter_complex` has the same effect.

Is there a different way to force the filtering to stop at the end of the input file?

EDIT: Using the `shortest=1` flag on the overlay filter also doesn't help, even in combination with `-shortest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the suggestions from both llogan and Gyan, here's what I came up with:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $INPUTFILE -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=c=black:t=fill[black]; [black][0:s:5]overlay=shortest=1[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v png -f image2pipe - | pike subspng.pike
```

Instead of creating an infinite-length source of black frames, this instead takes the original video stream, then covers the entire thing with a black box. NOTE: May require a newish version of FFMPEG for the `drawbox` filter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `shortest` option in the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

> `shortest`
> If set to 1, force the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates. Default value is 0.

```
ffmpeg -y -i $INPUTFILE -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:s:5]overlay=shortest=1[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v png -f image2pipe - | pike subspng.pike
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is different from -shortest? I've seen both referenced, and the best advice I could find was the opposite - that -shortest was the way to go. But just in case, I tried it, and it has the same result.

Comment: Interesting, okay. Will look into updating, even if that means building from source.

Comment: Actually, nope, still doesn't work - tested with ffmpeg version N-53260-ga37109d555-static from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ which should be today's build or thereabouts.

Comment: @rosuav Can you provide a link to the input file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, for reasons of copyright. But it's a bluray m2ts file.

Comment: `-shortest` is only relevant with multiple output streams, so not here. overlay `shortest=1` should work. I can only imagine that subtitle stream EOF isn't signaled.